# DiracDelta is seldom chosen as the answer

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

It is well known that

```
Limit[ ϵ/π/(x^2 + ϵ^2), ϵ -> 0]
```

is the Dirac Delta function

```
DiracDelta[x]
```

Yet Mathematica gives the incorrect answer as 0.

Comment: This is a math question, not a Mathematica question. The $\delta$-function is the limit of $\frac \epsilon {\pi(\epsilon^2+x^2)}$ as $\epsilon \to 0$ in the weak topology (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology as a first reading). This is not a usual limit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the issued raised is not really a problem; it is arises from the OP's misunderstanding of the result returned by Mathematica.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Limit[\[Epsilon]/\[Pi]/(x^2 + \[Epsilon]^2), \[Epsilon] -> 0,
  GenerateConditions -> True]
(* ConditionalExpression[0, x != 0] *)
```

This is correct. The limit does not exist for `x==0`. For certain restricted problems you may pragmatically take it to be `DiracDelta[x]`, but *Mathematica* will does not generally yield such a result except in the case of explicit Fourier/Laplace transforms.

Comment: "but Mathematica will does not generally yield such a result" IMO it should since it is used universally in Physics who are one of the main users of Mathematica.

Comment: The essential problem, I think, is that `DiracDelta` is mathematically hazardous. Physicists learn to tiptoe around the hazards, and it's thus very useful to us. But *Mathematica* isn't a physicist. It manipulates expressions using formal math without physical insight. That means that if you, as a physicist, understand that `DiracDelta` is safe to use for your problem, you may have to introduce it yourself.

Comment: I don't see what is "hazardous" given the fact that Mathematica already has an in built function called DiracDelta[x] for describing it. So the limit in questions does "converge" to this generalised function in the generalised sense of the limit. Since "generalised" functions are recognised by Mathematica generalised limits should do too. So the developers should take my advice and implement this instead of putting my question on hold as off topic.

Comment: Consider a 1 volt-second `DiracDelta` impulse applied to a one ohm resistor. It'll drive a coulomb through the resistor. How many joules will the resistor dissipate? You, a physicist, are smart enough not to ask this question. A formal algebra system isn't, and this kind of thing can appear in the million formal transformations that it goes through to get an answer. I don't know exactly how the developers chose to draw the line here, but in many cases you have to tell the system "the hazards are my responsibility" by explicitly using `DiracDelta` when you need it.

Comment: "A formal algebra system isn't (smart)" The whole point of my comment is to persuade the developers to make it smart so that an important user community (ie physicists) will find it useful.